# Storing Shapely polygons in MySQL

Tags: python, shapely, well-known-text, mysql

I have to store some polygons in a MySQL database. The polygons are in Plate Carrée (ESPG 32662) projection, but I also tried to first converting them to the usual latitude-longitude projection (ESPG 4326) and it did not work either.

First I upload the shapely polygon to the database:

```
polygon_text = my_shapely_polygon.to_wkt()
query = f"""
                INSERT INTO
                    lands (polygon_id, geometry)
                VALUES
                    ({id}, ST_GeomFromText({polygon_text}));
        """
```

The type of the column `geometry` in the database is set to `POLYGON`.
However, when I retrieve the geometry and do

```
shapely.wkb.loads(retrieved_polygon)
```

I get a point, not a polygon. 
The same thing happens if I try to upload the polygon as WKB.

Answer (score 1):

Change `wkb` to `wkt`.

```
shapely.wkt.loads(retrieved_polygon)
```

Comment: Can you extend your answer and add an explanation?